# How can I delete values from nested mapping after a sum

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereumjs, mapping, struct

I'm making an staking contract in solidity and i have used structs and nested mapping for saving users staking amount and its staking time,

At the time of calling unstake function msg.sender will withdraw his certain amount of deposited tokens.

for example:
a user has object of amount of tokens and its time of deposit.
amount : timestamp
`[{100, 156354536}, {200, 156354537}, {300, 156354536}]`

Now i want to withdraw or unstake 450 tokens and rest should be on their indexs.

Here's my code:

```
 struct Staking {
    uint value;
    uint stakingTime;
    uint reward;
}

mapping(address => Staking[]) public stakingInfo;


    // Unstaking Tokens (Withdraw) 
   function unstakeTokens(uint _withdrawAmount) public {
       uint balance;
       uint internalWithdrawAmount;
    
     // Fetch staking balance
    for (uint i = 0; i < stakingInfo[msg.sender].length; i++) {
        balance = balance + stakingInfo[msg.sender][i].value;
    }
    
    // Require amount greater than 0
    require(balance > 0, "staking balance cannot be 0");
    
         // Fetch staking balance
    for (uint i = 0; i < stakingInfo[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            
            delete stakingInfo[msg.sender][i];
        }
        
    }
    
    
    // Transfer Mock Dai tokens to this contract for staking
    daiToken.transfer(msg.sender, balance);

    // Reset staking balance
    stakingBalance[msg.sender] = 0;

    // Update staking status
    isStaking[msg.sender] = false;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to read your question several times (taking a break in between). It is practically unreadable IMO. I recommend rephrasing it to something that makes sense. Also, please consider getting rid of all the code which is unrelated of your actual problem.

Comment: This is the total code i want you to take notice in.

well let me rephrase it. But in general i'm confusing in making logic. let me rephrase.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to say - a large portion of total code seems likely irrelevant to your question (I'm guessing that, because - again - your question is unreadable). If you get rid of the irrelevant parts, then it might make it easier to understand what it is that you're trying to ask.

Comment: In addition to that, try to find a better way to rephrase `what i want is when user withdraw his certain amount so user can withdraw and i delete the index of that value and when sum of value meets so it withdraw tokens and staking time of other indexs should not change`. This couldn't make a sensible statement in any language that I can think of!!!

Comment: Okay I have tried to rephrase the question, I hope you understand the example now.

Comment: I have main issue in only unstake method, when user will be withdrawing his deposited tokens.

Comment: So why should we care about the rest of your code. Show only the function which you're having a problem with (alongside the relevant data structure, of course). It might help understanding your (still) unreadable question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113865/discussion-between-hamza-yasin-and-goodvibration).

Comment: Please check again brother.

Comment: `Now i want to withdraw or unstake 450 tokens and rest should be on their indexs` - there are countless many ways to do that. For example, I can withdraw 90 from the first entry, 190 from the second entry and 170 from the third entry. You'll need to come up with a more deterministic description of your requirement.